# Finding the sum of fibonacci numbers less than n

Tags: python-3.x, fibonacci

I have to find the sum of all fibonacci numbers before a value n. So the last fibonacci value that I get is less than or equal to n. For example sum_of_fibonacci(10) would be 0+1+1+2+3+5+8 since 8<10. I am having trouble limiting the fibonacci sequence to stop before it passes n. Where do I go from here?

```
sum_of_fibonacci(n):
    def fib(n):    
        if n == 0 or n == 1:
            return n
        else:
            return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

Comment: Did you consider lopping over `range(n)` and `sum` the returned values from your `fib` function ?

Comment: for fib(4), you want to stop at `0+1+1+2+3` and for fib(7) you want to stop at `0+1+1+2+3+5` ? Is that your problem? In the first case `3 < 4 < 5` and you want to stop at `3` and for the second `5 < 7 < 8` so you want it to stop at `5` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by storing all Fibonacci numbers that are less than n in in a list and then return its sum

```
def sum_of_fibonacci(n):
    if n == 0 : return 0
    fib = [0, 1]   #initializing the list of Fibonacci numbers
    i = 2   #position of next_fib
    next_fib = 1
    while next_fib <n :
        fib.append(next_fib)
        i += 1
        next_fib = fib[i-1] + fib[i-2]
    return sum(fib)
print(sum_of_fibonacci(10))
# 20
```

if you want to do this for multiple value you may consider calculating all the Fibonacci numbers in a range first and then return the sum of wished numbers :

```
MAX_RANGE = 10000   #we'll consider the first 10000 Fibonacci numbers
fib = [0, 1]
for i in range(2, MAX_RANGE):
    fib.append((fib[i-1] + fib[i-2]))
def sum_of_fibonacci(n):
    if n == 0 : return 0
    return sum([f for f in fib if f<n])
Q = int(input())   #input the number of test cases
for i in range(Q):
    to = int(input())   #input each test case
    print(sum_of_fibonacci(to))
# input : 2
# input : 10
# output : 20
# input : 100
# output : 232
```

By using the last method when searching for sum_of_fibonacci of Q test cases the complexity would be O(Q*n + MAX_RANGE) over O(Q*n^2) with the first one

Answer (score 0):

Updated my response based on this usecase: `For example sum_of_fibonacci(10) would be 0+1+1+2+3+5+8 since 8<10`

You can try to create a simple loop and print the values. I dont think you need an array.

Here's the space optimized solution. You may find other faster solutions.

```
def sum_of_fib(n):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    if n < 0:
        print ('Incorrect input')
    elif n in (0,1): return n
    else:
        s = 0
        while b <= n:
            s += b
            a,b = b,a+b
        return s

print ('sum of fib till 0:',sum_of_fib(0))
print ('sum of fib till 1:',sum_of_fib(1))
print ('sum of fib till 2:',sum_of_fib(2))
print ('sum of fib till 3:',sum_of_fib(3))
print ('sum of fib till 4:',sum_of_fib(4))
print ('sum of fib till 5:',sum_of_fib(5))
print ('sum of fib till 6:',sum_of_fib(6))
print ('sum of fib till 7:',sum_of_fib(7))
print ('sum of fib till 8:',sum_of_fib(8))
print ('sum of fib till 9:',sum_of_fib(9))
print ('sum of fib till 10:',sum_of_fib(10))
```

Output is:

```
sum of fib till 0: 0
sum of fib till 1: 1
sum of fib till 2: 4
sum of fib till 3: 7
sum of fib till 4: 7
sum of fib till 5: 12
sum of fib till 6: 12
sum of fib till 7: 12
sum of fib till 8: 20
sum of fib till 9: 20
sum of fib till 10: 20
```